# VIM Search/Replace spaces between 2 brackets or columns

Tags: regex, vim, replace

Given the following line:

```
[aaaa bbbb cccc dddd] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
```

How would you replace the spaces only between the first set of brackets in Vim? What would the /s command look like?

*Update:*

This is the intend outcome

```
    [aaaa_bbbb_cccc_dddd] [decimal](18, 0) NULL,
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be to visually select the contents of the `[]`ed string and perform the replacement just on that selection:

```
vi]:s/\%V \%V/_/g
```

This doesn't work very well if you're trying to do things programmatically, though.  In that case, you can match the entire `[]`ed string and use a [replacement expression](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#sub-replace-expression) to construct the result.

```
:s/\[[^\]]*\]/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '_', 'g')/g
```

Comment: the replacement expression is cool.  The best I had was replace the first space block, then press & until it told you that it couldn't find the pattern

Comment: the =substitute(submatch(0)... was what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with the normal setting of 'magic' you'd want to do

```
:s/] \[/][/
```

or more fancily

```
:s/]\zs\s\+\ze\[//
```

or with the magic level explicitly set in the regex

```
:s/\V]\zs\s\+\ze[//
```

\zs and \ze limit the substitution to the area that they enclose.

\M turns off magic completely, so every character or character combo not prefixed with `\` is taken literally.

'magic' (`:help 'magic'`) is a global option that determines how potentially-special characters in regexes are interpreted.

Comment: You forgot about look-behind and look-ahead (`s/]\@<=\s\+\[\@=//`).

Comment: It's `\V` that makes everything other than `\ `  be interpreted literally.  `\M` is one step between `\V` and the default setup.  Changing the value of `'magic'` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @jamessan oops, thanks.  Fixed.

@ZyX \zs & \ze are easier to remember and I think faster, so I prefer to use them when possible.

Upon reading the update I've discovered that my answer is totally not an answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can always go for interactive find and replace, which can be done with flag `c`